# Javascript function not working onblur or onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html-table

I am fairly new to ajax and I am unsure as to why my function is not firing. I have a table built up dynamically with values from a MySQL database. I am trying to make the table able to be edited inline.
The parts of the table I want to edit are built as follows....

```
<tr class="table-row">
    <td><?php echo $row['idcpu']; ?></td>
    <?php 
    echo "<td contenteditable=\"true\" onBlur=\"saveToDatabase(this,'name','".$row['idcpu']."');\" onClick=\"showEdit(this);\">".$row['name']." </td>";
    echo "<td contenteditable=\"true\" onBlur=\"saveToDatabase(this,'description','".$row['idcpu']."');\" onClick=\"showEdit(this);\">".$row['description']."</td>";
    echo "<td contenteditable=\"true\" onBlur=\"saveToDatabase(this,'price','".$row['idcpu']."');\" onClick=\"showEdit(this);\">".$row['price']."</td>";
    echo "<td contenteditable=\"true\" onBlur=\"saveToDatabase(this,'quantity','".$row['idcpu']."');\" onClick=\"showEdit(this);\">".$row['quantity']."</td>"; ?>
</tr>
```

And Javascript as so.....

```
<script>
    function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {
        $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF url(Loading_icon.gif) no-repeat right");
        $.ajax({
            url: "update/cpu.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id,
            success: function(data){
                $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");
            }
       });
    }
</script>
```

I have tried many different ways of outputting the code to html so I know that isn't the issue but I could just have easily missed something I need as I as I said I am fairly new. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Instead of using `contenteditable` use `textarea` or `input`. `contenteditable` is very complex and not friendly at all. `textarea` and `input` are standard, reliable, and there are a couple of crossbrowser ways to manipulate them.

Comment: I have started to use input now, while I have managed to get my onclick working my onblur still does not fire the function saveToDatabase. The background does not change, no image is loading and the PHP page is not running

Comment: For form elements instead of `innerHTML` you use `obj.value` for JS or `$(obj).val()` for jQuery. Instead of `onblur` use `onchange` . There are details for the use of forms you need to be acquainted with. This resource is a great start: http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working just fine. You can take a look at here:

[JSBin Example](https://jsbin.com/josahifuva/edit?html,js,output)

I've tested it with Chrome v49.

As @zer00ne mentioned, you should try using `<input>` by nesting it inside of the `<td>` elements and run the ajax call on input change. Browser Support is a lot better.

Comment: I have changed it so I use text input instead of contenteditable now. Although you say it is working the fields I edit are editable but the change will not be kept. The php file I reference is not running and the css changes are not happening. Am I expecting my code to do something else? I just need it to send the values to the PHP script

Comment: I think I forgot to mention that my php page runs a script which will update the database with the information entered